# replace nth-match of a regexp in a string

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, string

I'm looking for a function that can replace the nth-match in a string.

Here's an example. `2` is the index of the nth-match, `[0-9]+` is the regular expression to search. `foo` is the replacement and `"a 100 b 200 c 300"` is the string in which the replacement takes place.

```
ELISP> (replace-nth-regexp-in-string 2 "[0-9]+" "foo" "a 100 b 200 c 300")
```

```
a 100 b foo c 300
```

I haven't found a built-in expression to do this, so I believe I'll have to write my own. Any advices are appreciated.

Comment: It'll just be a `while` loop, to firstly match the regexp N times, and then (provided that was successful) `replace-match` for the most-recent match data.

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(setq toto  "a 100 b 200 c 300")

(setq bar  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\([^0-9]+\\)\\([0-9]+\\)\\)\\{2\\}"
                                     "foo" ; Replacement string
                                     toto  ; Input string to match
                                     nil
                                     nil
                                     3))   ; Index of subexp match to replace
```

`toto` is unchanged.  `bar` is `"a 100 b foo c 300"`

The `\\{2\\}` in the regexp says the match is against two such groups (each of which has two subgroups).

The `3` as argument says replace the 3rd group in the match (the match being the text corresponding to the two matched subgroups).

The first group of the match is the outer group, the second is the group matching non-digits, and the third is the group matching digits.

`C-h f replace-regexp-in-string` says:

> `replace-regexp-in-string` is a compiled Lisp function in ‘subr.el’.
>
> `(replace-regexp-in-string REGEXP REP STRING &optional FIXEDCASE LITERAL SUBEXP START)`
>
> Replace all matches for `REGEXP` with `REP` in `STRING`.
>
> Return a new string containing the replacements.
>
> Optional arguments `FIXEDCASE`, `LITERAL` and `SUBEXP` are like the
> arguments with the same names of function `replace-match`.  If `START`
> is non-`nil`, start replacements at that index in `STRING`.
>
> `REP` is either a string used as the `NEWTEXT` arg of `replace-match` or a
> function.  If it is a function, it is called with the actual text of each
> match, and its value is used as the replacement text.  When `REP` is called,
> the match data are the result of matching `REGEXP` against a substring
> of `STRING`, the same substring that is the actual text of the match which
> is passed to `REP` as its argument.
>
> To replace only the first match (if any), make `REGEXP` match up to `\'`
> and replace a sub-expression, e.g.
>
> `(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(foo\\).*\\'" "bar" " foo foo" nil nil 1) => " bar foo"`